# jquery's removeAttr function inside $(document).ready doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got stuck with some trouble. 
I got a page, where I use @media to create mobile and tablet version separatly. In mobile version I use mmenu jquery plugin, to make a sliding menu. In tablet version I do not want to use this menu, but still planning to use it's html. So I decided to remove id, that shows mmenu plugin where it need to make sliding menu. But for some reason juery's removeAttr does not work as I expected. 
Ps: I'm pretty new to js, so I might not know about thihgs related to browser workings.

I got this code (html is pretty simple - nav, that wraps a bunch of ul's) :

```
   var func = function() {
            var width = $(window).width();
            var menu = $(".menu");
            /*if it is tablet*/
            if (width > 401) {
                menu.removeAttr("id");
            }

            /*loading mmenu*/
            $(function() {
                $('#my-menu').mmenu({
                    slidingSubmenus: false,
                    zposition: "next"
                });
            });

        };

        $(document).ready = func();
```

I'll be very happy if someone clarifies where is my mistake.

Comment: You cannot be sure `width > 401` is evaluated correct, eg width is considered as a number. Use `parseInt(width) > 401` instead, and see what happends.

Comment: @davidkonrad jquery's width method always returns a number.

Comment: Removing the ID doesn't seem like a good approach. Why not just init the plugin only when `width < 402`?

Comment: `$(document).ready = func();` this is incorrect.

Comment: P.S. `$(function() {` is the same thing as `$(document).ready(function(){`.  There's no reason to use one inside the other.

Comment: @Scimonster, you are right, didnt think about that :( But typically a good starting point for looking for errors, when people assumes a var is of a certain type.

Comment: @davidkonrad even it was true, that didn't solve problem, because I've putted alert inside "if" - and it was working well. :)

Comment: @errdayvillain, It was also a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: @isherwood, thanks this is good idea, my mind was closed because of trouble.)

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, thanks about PS, good advice! But why is setting $(document).ready = func() wrong? (Completely wrong or just bad parctice?) As I understand it similar to setting one variable to another. Update: tested my code - it clearly is completely wrong.)

Comment: @davidkonrad oh, I get it!) Anyway thanks, I keep your advice when I will work with something that does not check for values.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're binding document.ready incorrectly. It should be

```
$(document).ready(func);
```

You don't set the property, and you don't call your function.

Comment: So, am I understading this right: in my code I was trying to set value of ready with my func, but according to documentation I must pass my function as a property to .ready()?

Comment: @errdayvillain: Yes.  `.ready()` is already a property, it's a function.  You need to call it.  You were *replacing* that function with a new value :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the ID from `#my-menu`, you could move the function to create the menu inside the width-checking function. That way, the menu is only created if the width is wider than 401. Otherwise it's skipped altogether.

```
if (width > 401) {
    $(function(){
        $('#my-menu').mmenu(...);
    });
}
```

Comment: Right, except is the reverse--mobile menu for small screens.